# How do I iterate through a pivot table slicer excluding items with no data?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I'm working on a macro that will loop through a pivot table slicer saving each page as a PDF while I do it. The only problem is the code is including slicer items that have no data (i.e. I've got 100 employees but only 40 have data and I'm still getting 100 pdfs with blanks on 60 of them). Is there a way to only loop through slicer items that are visible/have data? My code is below!

```
    Sub PowerPivotLoopSlicerPrintPDF()
Dim sC As SlicerCache
Dim SL As SlicerCacheLevel
Dim sI As SlicerItem
Dim c As Long

Set sC = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Employee_ID1") 
Set SL = sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1)
c = 1 


'LOOP THROUGH SLICER
Do While c <= sC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1  
    For Each sI In SL.SlicerItems
        If sI.Selected = True Then
        SlicerverdiIndex = c
    Exit For
        End If
    Next sI

Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String


FPath = "FILE PATH HERE"
FName = Range("C4") & "-" & Range("C6")

'Define WHAT to print and how to build file name
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
False

If SlicerverdiIndex = 1 Then
    SlicerverdiIndex = sC.SlicerCacheLevels.Item.Count + 1
End If
sC.VisibleSlicerItemsList = SL.SlicerItems(SlicerverdiIndex - 1).Name

c = c + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You can check the `HasData` property of the `SlicerItem` object, for example `If sI.HasData Then`.

Comment: Hey Domenic! Thanks for the reply. So whenever I do that nothing really happens. I attempted to add it as an AND condition (If sI.Selected = True AND sI.HasData = True) but I get the same result. Did I possibly put it in the wrong place?